# "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" when executing FullTextSqlQuery?

Tags: search, visual-studio, fulltextsqlquery

I am using a FullTextSqlQuery to grab some data from a SharePoint instance.  Initially I had a fairly simple where clause in which I filtered the results by the content type and everything worked fine.

I then tried to add some date filtering which added a condition like:

```
 AND mypublishstartdate <= '11/9/2011'
```

to the end.  Unfortunately I am now getting the error:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been
>   returned from a call to a COM component.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a managed property called `mypublishstartdate` which has a crawlable property mapped to it?

Comment: Yes I have that

Comment: Try formatted your date in Year to Day format, then. YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: No more errors!  Not getting any records now, but I can figure that out.  Thanks!  Any idea why that fixes it?

Comment: It's the format datetimes are stored in the database, Year to second, YYYYMMDDTHHmmssZ (also known as ISO8601).

Comment: Awesome, you're the man James!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, recycling the application pool where search was running fixed this issue